# Selection formula in View Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a form (`NewDocumentForm`) where I create documents. And also there is a field (name: `reader_field`) that keeps roles of `ACL` that can read this document.
Next I create a view (`MainView`) to display this documents and I have a problem with View Selection formula.
My task is to show in MainView the documents to user where he has role to read this document (this role in `reader_field`).

So in Selection Formula I write the next:

`SELECT (@Contains(reader_field; @UserRoles));` <- there is not that I need...

`SELECT @IsMember(reader_field; @UserRoles);` <- there is not that I need...

If you understand my question please give me advice. Thanks.

Comment: You can only see documents in view if you are member of the reader field

Comment: ...or of an Authors-type field. Remember, being listed in an Authors field gives you *explicit* permission to edit the document (provided that you have at least Author access to the database), and you can't edit what you can't see. The field flag set is ``SUMMARY READ WRITE ACCESS` on an Authors field. It's surprising how few people seem to know that (or at least understand the implications), so if you weren't aware of it, you're not alone.

Answer (score 3):

You can show *all* documents in view. You don't need to select the documents for user as the user can see only those documents in view the user has access to.

Actually, @UserRoles won't work in a view SELECT as the view is calculated on server. You could use private views but that has a lot of side effects you probably won't deal with. So, don't worry. Users will see only those documents in view they are allowed to by their roles.

Comment: But I have a problem that all users see all document and I want to make the selection from all the documents to show those document where in reader_field has entered role that have user who opened a view

Comment: If all users see all documents then the readers field with listed roles is probably useless as readers field. Use `SELECT @Contains(reader_field; "[")` to show all documents which have a role in field reader_field. Show the roles in view's column as category.

Comment: When you look at the document properties and select the reader_field entry in the scrolling list of items, what do you see listed for the field type?  If it is not listed as "SUMAMRY READ-ACCESS NAMES", then you have not set it up correctly and it will not work as you expect.

Comment: The question is: is it ok that users can see **all** documents? Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Is the field reader_field actually a Notes "Readers access" field ?

You can tell by checking the field in the Notes document properties box. You should see for that field:

Field Flags: SUMMARY READ-ACCESS NAMES

If that's the case, then the field reader_field will automatically limit who can see those documents in the view to those with the role in the field.

So your selection formula can allow everyone to view it, and the readers_field will limit it as necessary. This works for web applicaiton & Notes client.

Be sure to add a 'catch all' readers field as well as it's entirely possible to accidentally hide doecuments with a Readers field such that no-one can see them. If you add for example an [Admin] role (it can be in another field of type Readers on same doc) which only support staff have, then you have a way to see all documents, for support purposes.

If it's just a normal text field called reader_field....

If a Notes application:
About your only option is to use private views (bit too much to explain here)

If a Web application:
You can categorise the view by the reader_field and use a form to include the view with a view embedded element. Use the "Restrict To Category" setting to the user's role (if they have >1 role then you'll probably have to put some logic in to work out which one is appropriate)

Another alternative would be to display the view using an XPage, which allows you to trim the data as it's displayed.